# Uicollectionview cell only wraps around text

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, nslayoutconstraint

My swift code collectionviewcell is in all code not storyboard. As you can see in my photo below. The uicollectionviewcell is wrapped around a single number I want there to be much more space in the collectionviewcell. I dont know how to add a hieght constraint to the uicollectionviewcell with the code below. In short just make each collection cell 100 height and 100 width thanks.

[image]

```
import UIKit

class Cell: UICollectionViewCell {

    static var identifier: String = "Cell"

    weak var textLabel: UILabel!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        let textLabel = UILabel(frame: .zero)
        textLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.contentView.addSubview(textLabel)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            self.contentView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: textLabel.centerXAnchor),


            self.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100),
            self.contentView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: textLabel.centerYAnchor),

        ])
        self.textLabel = textLabel
        self.reset()
        textLabel.backgroundColor = .yellow
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        self.reset()
    }

    func reset() {
        self.textLabel.textAlignment = .center
    }
}
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    var data: [Int] = Array(0..<10)

    override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()

        let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
        collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.view.addSubview(collectionView)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            self.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: collectionView.topAnchor),
            self.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: collectionView.bottomAnchor),
            self.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: collectionView.leadingAnchor),
            self.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: collectionView.trailingAnchor),
        ])
        self.collectionView = collectionView
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.collectionView.dataSource = self
        self.collectionView.delegate = self
        self.collectionView.register(Cell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: Cell.identifier)
        self.collectionView.alwaysBounceVertical = true
        self.collectionView.backgroundColor = .brown
    }
}

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                        numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.data.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                        cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: Cell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! Cell
        let data = self.data[indexPath.item]
        cell.textLabel.text = String(data)


        return cell
    }
}

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    }
}

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                        layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                        sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: collectionView.bounds.width, height: 60)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                        layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                        insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
        return UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0) //.zero
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                        layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                        minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 0
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                        layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                        minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 0
    }
}
```

Comment: look through UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout it has func to size cells

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54592100/swift-how-to-adjust-uicollectionviewcells-ratio-for-different-ios-device-size/54592673#54592673

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update sizeForItemAt method to return w = 100 h = 100

```
extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                        layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                        sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
    }
}
```

Comment: to fill the collectionView completely , return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.size.width, height: 100)